MySQL: Get Previous Years View Count
I have SQL that gets the past 60 days and the sum of view for each of these days and all works fine. I'm trying to take these past 60 days and get the same days view counts from the previous year.
So say for example today's record is (views, date):
234, 2024-10-07

I want to get this days record from last year, like:
75, 2023-10-07

Current SQL for the past 60 days view counts:
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(`adv_views`), 0) AS `total_views`
, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`adv_year`, '-', `adv_month`, '-', `adv_day`), '%Y-%m-%d') AS `date`
FROM `art_daily_views`
GROUP BY `adv_year`, `adv_month`, `adv_day`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 0, 60;

I've modified the SQL to try and move it back a year based on the current 60 days, but it returns nothing:
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(`adv_views`), 0) AS `total_views`
, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`adv_year`, '-', `adv_month`, '-', `adv_day`), '%Y-%m-%d') AS `date`
FROM `art_daily_views`
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`adv_year`, '-', `adv_month`, '-', `adv_day`), '%Y-%m-%d') <= STR_TO_DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY `adv_year`, `adv_month`, `adv_day`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 0, 60;

The table structure is:
adv_day, adv_month, adv_year, adv_views
'07', '10', '2024', '1'
'07', '10', '2024', '3'
'07', '10', '2024', '2'
'06', '10', '2024', '1'
'06', '10', '2024', '1'


without digging into that deeply: maybe remove the limit at first.

@ErhardDinhobl even with LIMIT removed it returns nothing.

and then make sure:
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(adv_year, '-', adv_month, '-', adv_day), '%Y-%m-%d') <= STR_TO_DATE (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d') does not truncate only to 12 months. ;)

Your WHERE clause seems to be the one causing the issue. You are trying to compare the dates using DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) but filtering the days, months and years separately, which don't go aligned.
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(adv_year, '-', adv_month, '-', adv_day), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH - INTERVAL 60 DAY)
Change your WHERE and BETWEEN clause with this one and I'm hopeful that you'll get your results.

Try this,
SELECT
  COALESCE(SUM(`adv_views`), 0) AS `total_views`,
  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`adv_year`, '-', `adv_month`, '-', `adv_day`), '%Y-%m-%d') AS `date`
FROM
  `art_daily_views`
WHERE
  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`adv_year`, '-', `adv_month`, '-', `adv_day`), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND CURDATE()
  OR STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`adv_year`, '-', `adv_month`, '-', `adv_day`), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR + 60 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY
  `adv_year`, `adv_month`, `adv_day`
ORDER BY
  `date` DESC;


It's not advisable to use the character values when working with dates. If we convert your day-month-year columns into date data type then we can use some date math to solve your problem using just Where clause.
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table tbl (adv_day Varchar(2), adv_month Varchar(2), adv_year Varchar(4), adv_views Varchar(6));
Insert Into tbl
VALUES ( '07', '10', '2024', '1' ),
       ( '07', '10', '2024', '3' ), 
       ( '07', '10', '2024', '2' ), 
       ( '06', '10', '2024', '1' ), 
       ( '06', '10', '2024', '1' ), 
--
       ( '07', '10', '2023', '2' ),
       ( '07', '10', '2023', '1' ), 
       ( '06', '10', '2023', '1' ), 
       ( '06', '10', '2023', '1' ), 
       ( '06', '10', '2023', '2' );

Inner query creates adv_date column of DATE data type converted from your character columns. Since you need the Sum of views per day (outer query Selection list grouped by adv_date) for last 60 days of this year  and the same period of the year before - the Where clause should filter the data so you can get what you wanted.
--      S Q L : 
Select    adv_date, Sum(adv_views) as sum_views
From      ( Select t.*,
                   STR_TO_DATE( Concat(adv_year, '-', adv_month, '-', adv_day), '%Y-%m-%d' ) as adv_date
            From   tbl t
          ) x
Where     adv_date Between DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY ) And CURDATE() 
        OR
          adv_date Between DATE_SUB( DATE_SUB(  CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY ), INTERVAL 12 MONTH )  And DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH ) 
Group by  adv_date

/*    R e s u l t : 
adv_date    sum_views
----------  ---------
2024-10-07          6
2024-10-06          2
2023-10-07          3
2023-10-06          4      */

See the fiddle here.
